# get data from specific item in recyclerview according to position passed from firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have created a simple notes app in which I'm storing data in firebase. Showing the list of notes(time and few words of a note) in recyclerview. Now I want when I click in a particular note, it take to different activity where the details of the note will be shown. I am not able to get data from firebase column wise(note and time).

[image]

**CustomAdapter**

> Here I'm sending the position of the item clicked to **NotesDetails** class

```
public class CustomAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Model> models;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> models){
        this.context = context;
        this.models = models;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.time_text.setText(models.get(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()).getText());
        holder.string_text.setText(models.get(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()).getNotes());
        holder.constraintLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NotesDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return models.size(); }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView string_text, time_text;
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            string_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            time_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeshow);
            constraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
        }
    }
}
```

**NotesDetails**

> I want to show time and details of particular item here in **testShow** and **timeShow**

```
public class NotesDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Model> models;
    TextView textShow, timeShow;
    DBHelper myDB;
    DatabaseReference dbReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes_details);

        textShow = findViewById(R.id.notesShow);
        timeShow = findViewById(R.id.timeshow);
        myDB = new DBHelper(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int position = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("position"));

        dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Model").child("notes");
        dbReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Model m1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                    textShow.setText((CharSequence) m1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No error. when I click in any item of recyclerview it took to another activity. There it should show time and details of note from firebase I don't know how to get it done based on the posiotion which I'm sending from customAdpater to NotesDetails @AlexMamo

Comment: You should add to the intent the entire object, not only the position and get it in the new activity.